# Azure Function Call from Data Factory

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-queues

I've got an Azure function that hosts a Docker image with some Python scripts.
Currently there is a "function.json" file

```
{
  "scriptFile": "calcs.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "AzureQueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Python script starts with the following to read the messages in in JSON format;

```
def main(msg: azfunc.QueueMessage)
```

I'm looking at trying to change this so that the function can receive a message from Data Factory directly instead of from an Queue.
Has anyone got any good sources for how to do this?

Quick update - I think I may have gotten this, but I've ran into a 403 when deployed. (Will post an update on what I've done if I can get around the 403.

It looks like I'm missing some configuration like a SAS for Data Factory to talk to the Function.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function activity allows you to run Azure Functions in an Azure Data Factory or Synapse pipeline. To run an Azure Function, you must create a linked service connection. Then you can use the linked service with an activity that specifies the Azure Function that you plan to execute.

[Azure Function activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity)

Comment: Thanks - The link doesn't work though.

Comment: Please try the link now @Dan

Comment: Thanks - I've had a look through, I think it's something to do with us locking down the IP Range, when it's not locked down the function can be reached, when it is locked down and we've added an app registration it 403's.
We are working on troubleshooting it though.

Comment: if you have to check the networking on the ADF side, it you are using the Private end point or manage Vnet with ADF. you will run into this issue. 

Share the error if you can

Comment: Hi,
Got around that by unrestricting IP in networking and using App Registration to lock it down to certain Users & Managed Identities.
Only problem now is when deploying a function it goes through as successful, but there is no function registered and when visiting the <site>.scm.<azurewebsites> the function.json and initialisation file for c# or Python aren't showing.